# using .keypress and .keydown side by side

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to capture normal text with upper and lower case letters, but I also want to pick up the key codes for alt, ctrl, esc, etc. I have attempted to run the two jquery functions .keypress and .keydown, and only accept special keys from .keydown, but when they are together, they only give to result of one. I am using Chrome, but I also need support for as many other browsers as possible.

Comment: `if(event.altKey && event.ctrlKey) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the state of special keys using [jQuery.Event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) which is the first argument of the callback from a listener:

http://jsbin.com/epuqig/2/embed?live

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('input').on('keydown', function(event) {
        // event.shiftKey
        // event.ctrlKey
        // Also to fetch the keyCode use:
        // event.which
        if ( event.which == 8 && event.shiftKey ) {
            // Backspace and shift key is pressed
        }
    }); 
});
```

---

You can go vanilla if you don't care about old browsers:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    [].forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
        input.addEventListener('keydown', keydownHandler, false);
    });
}, false);

function keydownHandler(event) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 8 && event.shiftKey ) {
        // Backspace and shift key is pressed!
    }
}
```

As you can see this is almost the same code snippets but the second one want work in < IE9

Comment: @Christoph OP have specified jQuery as an option.

Comment: no offense, I just wanted to state that this is native. Many people sadly can't distinguish anymore nowadays.

Comment: @Christoph The problem with vanilla is if you are targeting < IE9

Comment: I admit, you are right. And thanks for adding the vanilla code... +1 ;)

Comment: If anyone would like to know more about the fantastic lightweight vanilla framework you should visit this site: http://vanilla-js.com/

Comment: hehe, did you just copy that from my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17149838/1047823)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode;
        if(e.altKey) // you can also use - e.ctrlKey , e.shiftKey
          // alt key
    }).keyup(function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode;
    });
});
```